# How to differentiate visually the white spaces in Vim?

Tags: whitespace

My goal were to somehow make visible, if a whitespace is space, tab, or even newline (and, ideally, in case of newline I would be happy to see `\r\n` and `\n` differently).

I am thinking to a similar thing as the GUI text editors can do.

Is it somehow with Vim also possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, look at [`:help listchars`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27listchars%27).

`listchars` is a string that will be parsed when `list` is set to determine what to render for certain special characters. You can set `listchars` in your `.vimrc` like so:

```
set listchars=eol:!,tab:>=,trail:.
set list
```

This will use the `!` character to show the end of every line, tabs like `>===` (assuming four-space tabs), and *trailing* spaces with a `.` character. The characters are highlighted with the `SpecialKey` group.

In addition, you can include the following tokens in `listchars`:

- `extends:<character>` for the last character in a long line
- `precedes:<character>` for the first character in a long line
- `conceal:<character>` for concealed text
- `nbsp:<character>` for non-breaking spaces

Note that you cannot get vim to display visible whitespace for spaces that are not trailing without a relatively modern version of vim; check `if has("patch710")` to see if `space` is supported in `listchars`.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with `:set list`. The Characters displayed for the different whitespace chars can be controlled by `:set listchars`. See the help topics for detailed information. Here's an example from my .vimrc:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:.,extends:#,nbsp:.
```

Comment: great. And how can I change the color of the markers thus shown?  At the moment they're blue.  Would like light grey or something off-white. Guessed "listcolor" but no.

Comment: @projix I have not tested it but this answer shows how to change the colors: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6140/117 - tl;dr set the highlight colors for the respective highlight classes "NonText" and "SpecialKey".