# How to dim characters from :set list

Tags: highlight

I like to have `:set list` on so that I can tell if things are spaces or tabs. My tabs show as `>---` which is nice, but they are the same color are the text, is there a way to dim them so they're less distracting?

Comment: Did you read *all* of `:help 'list'` and `:help 'listchars'`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`:help 'listchars'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27listchars%27) mentions:

```
    The "NonText" highlighting will be used for "eol", "extends" and
    "precedes".  "SpecialKey" for "nbsp", "space", "tab" and "trail".
    hl-NonText hl-SpecialKey
```

And if we go to [`:help hl-SpecialKey`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl%2dSpecialKey) we read:

```
SpecialKey      Meta and special keys listed with ":map", also for text used
                to show unprintable characters in the text, 'listchars'.
                Generally: text that is displayed differently from what it
                really is.
```

You can change this with the [`:highlight`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3ahighlight) command, or `:hi` for short:

```
:hi SpecialKey ctermfg=grey guifg=grey70
```

Note that this *also* change the colours of non-printable characters; for example the `^M` when you're dealing with a file that mixes Unix and DOS line endings.