# Any way to display *all* characters?

Tags: whitespace

So, I got it that Vim has no option to display all characters (including <del>whitespace</del> and CR and LF distinctly)

I already saw the question [How to Display Hidden Characters in vim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74485/how-to-display-hidden-characters-in-vim) and others on stackexchange.

Is there at least a plugin to do that? I wasn't able to find any.

EDIT:

I found out (from [this comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/727/how-to-differentiate-visually-the-white-spaces-in-vim/729#729)) that recent versions of Vim (since [patch 7.4.710](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/79278367337be1e9a12222698642dcce0af1e059)) have a `space` option of `listchars`.
The dot `.` is quite good for it, but you can also use unicode characters such as the middle dot `·`.
That solves perfectly the problem with whitespace, so there's no need of a plugin for that.
The problems with line terminators still stand though, and there might be no way to fix them...

Comment: Your link has an accepted answer (`set list`), what's wrong with it?

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/questions/463785/how-do-i-get-vim-to-show-trailing-whitespace-but-use-blank-spaces-for-tabs.

Comment: @VanLaser With that inner spaces can't be clearly distinguished (for example with a colored middle dot as several editors do) and CR and LF can be told apart only if a file has mixed line endings, and even then there's no way to tell if there's a LF at the end of the file or not (there's always a single "$" displayed), and "$" also means either LF in an all-LF file or CRLF in an all-CRLF file.

Comment: @PhilippFrank I already read it, doesn't help.

Comment: About inner spaces: they are not different characters, right? They are still "normal" spaces - for that you can add a 'match' rule if I'm not mistaken. For the 2nd issue - again, you can add matches that parse your file and syntax highlight the line for example, if it ends in a different "Enter" than you wish. Just to suggest a different approach, maybe it can help.

Comment: @gbr What do you mean it doesn't help? It did work when I tried it, if I did not misunderstand your intention. (e) Ah ok, your intention goes beyond what list does/can do, so maybe you should try VanLaser's suggestion.

Comment: @VanLaser With :match you can only highlight things, if I'm not mistaken; having spaces of a different color doesn't help in any way, I want to tell apart one character from the other, a continuous stripe of color is no better than a continuous stripe of white.
For the 2nd, I just want to see clearly all the characters, I don't want to have to remember to check what options are set for the current file ('fileformat', 'eol'...), and preferably not to launch scripts either. The characters are there, I want to see them.

Comment: I want to know what I (or my editor) put in a file, and I can't constantly switch to another software. If there's no way this will be a major reason for me to ditch vim.

Comment: You can ditch Vim any time for all we care but you can also make your question easier to understand with a visual example. What we understand from your question is that you want to see an `a` when you insert an `a` or a ` ` when you insert a `space`.

Comment: @romainl Oh come on it's a standard feature. I'm pretty sure that a person aware of a plugin who does it would understand the question right away

Comment: Again, is an "inner space" a different character than "space", or not?

Comment: @VanLaser I'm sorry, I remarked _inner_ space because the `listchar` option does allow to set a character for trailing spaces, and I mistakenly understood that it also permitted to set one for space at the beginning of the lines, with `precedes`.
Thus I thought that the only space it didn't cover was the "inner" space, that is that interior to the lines.
I now saw that `precedes` has nothing to do with it though (so it's even more limited).
I don't want to treat "inner" space differently, I'd like that all spaces be displayed with a different symbol.

Comment: @VanLaser I noticed that at least in the GUI version you can set a specific font for an highlight group, so I think I could theoretically do what I want for the spaces with your solution, by making a font with my chosen symbol. However it's not that straightforward, I was looking for a ready solution (especially one that addresses the line endings too).

Comment: @VanLaser I found out that recent versions support a complete solution for whitespace, see the edit

Comment: Great. FWIW, when I open a DOS-type line-terminated file in Vim, it does show a differently-colored `^M` at the end of the line - but that probably depends on the file encoding settings. Perhaps try playing with `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` Linux commands on a dummy file, loading it into Vim, and see how it behaves.

Comment: @VanLaser Yes it varies with the fileformat settings, as I said in the [first comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7619/any-vim-plugin-to-display-all-characters#comment12548_7619)

Comment: Line breaks are obvious. Put `&ff` in your status line if you want to know what it is.

Comment: Vim displays characters in fixed width cells. How are you having trouble spotting spaces?